# add a unit after the text input in an input field angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know you can have a unit next to an input field using spans and what not but that doesnt look the best and it has a lot of room for error, like the value going past the unit

so say I have an input for weight and want to have kg at the end of what a user types so

`80kg`

is there a way I can dynamically add the 'kg' to the end of the number in the input??

I have an input like so..

```
<input [(ngModel)]="toolValue" type="number" class="tool_input tool_input__value" placeholder="Enter your value" required>
```

I basically want to do something like this

```
toolValue.onInput === toolValue + 'kg';
```

is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

> is this possible

Yes. But would be an awful experience.

A few things you will have to do:

- Cursor management: Make sure the user can't edit the `'kg'`
- Selection management: Perhaps you don't want `kg` to be selectable.

Its really up to you what you want and the edge cases you want to deal with. I would just style an extra `span` at the end.

Comment: Yes true, didn't think of those possibilities